# Spring boot, JPA, Hibernate and H2 DB tests - Sequence not working - Unexpected code path"; SQL statement: call next value for seq_my_jobs [50000-193]

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, sequence, h2

I have an entity on my spring boot app:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_JOBS")
public class InstallationJobEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(generator="SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQUENCE_GENERATOR",sequenceName="SEQ_MY_JOBS", allocationSize=100)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CONFIGURATION_DATA")
    @Lob
    private String configurationData;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getConfigurationData() {
        return configurationData;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setConfigurationData(String configurationData) {
        this.configurationData = configurationData;
    }
}
```

And for my tests I configure H2 DB on my application.yml:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        database: H2
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
    properties:
        hibernate:
            dialect: common.H2Dialect
    datasource:
        initialize: true
        schema: schema.sql
        data: data.sql
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;Mode=Oracle;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
        username:
        platform: h2
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
        testWhileIdle: true
        validationQuery: SELECT 1 from DUAL
```

On schema.sql I create the table and sequence (I tested it directly with JdbcTemplate and it's working)

When running my tests I get this exception:

```
2017-02-10 15:07:47.764 ERROR 22618 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
call next value for seq_my_jobs [50000-193]

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.save(Unknown Source)
    at softwaremanagement.services.dao.DAOServiceImpl.createInstallationJob(DAOServiceImpl.java:65)
    at softwaremanagement.services.BLServiceImpl.installationRequest(BLServiceImpl.java:51)
    at softwaremanagement.orchestration.actors.BLIntegrationTest.integrationWithMockGWFromBLServiceLevel(BLIntegrationTest.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator$1.getNextValue(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:506)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
call next value for seq_my_jobs [50000-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:213)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:242)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:255)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.addLock(Session.java:842)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.doLock2(MVTable.java:254)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.doLock1(MVTable.java:202)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.lock(MVTable.java:167)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.lockMeta(Database.java:909)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.removeSchemaObject(Database.java:1842)
    at org.h2.table.Table.removeChildrenAndResources(Table.java:530)
    at org.h2.table.TableView.removeChildrenAndResources(TableView.java:414)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.cleanTempTables(Session.java:948)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:643)
    at org.h2.schema.Sequence.flush(Sequence.java:302)
    at org.h2.schema.Sequence.getNext(Sequence.java:269)
    at org.h2.expression.SequenceValue.getValue(SequenceValue.java:30)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Call.query(Call.java:65)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:110)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)
    ... 79 more
```

The main issue is:
**Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
call next value for seq_my_jobs [50000-193]**

I also tried to implement my own H2 dialect with (all the commented code didn't work as well...):

```
public class H2Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect {
@Override
public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
//        return "SELECT "+ sequenceName + ".nextval";
//        return "SELECT "+sequenceName+".nextval from DUAL";
//        return "SELECT "+"NEXTVAL('"+sequenceName+"')";
        return "SELECT SEQ_MY_JOBS.nextVal from DUAL";
    }
```

}

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running H2 in Oracle compatibility mode `Mode=Oracle`, use the oracle dialect:

```
 properties:
        hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: Tried it just now - I got the same exception: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
select seq_my_jobs.nextval from dual [50000-193]

Comment: My bet is on case-sensitive match. Please remove `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` and try again. H2 docs says setting it to false is experimental.

Comment: Tried it already - same exception appears. I feel it got to do with when H2 creating the sequence, or when it allow start using it. When trying run the query: select seq_my_jobs.nextval from dual with jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet it didn't work, till I run it with jdbcTemplate.queryForInt, which return a result. After that - it worked with with jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet as well